# App Store says the file for El Capitan is too old

Tags: mac, macos

I want to reinstall El Capitan. After re=downloading from the App Store, a popup message says the file is too old. I absolutely want to revert to this OS, as I have had numerous issues with Sierra.

I would appreciate help in this issue, thanks.

MacBook Air
OS Sierra 10.12

EtreCheck version: 3.0.6 (315)
Report generated 2016-10-21 14:18:39
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime 2:05
Performance: Excellent

Click the [Support] links for help with non-Apple products.
Click the [Details] links for more information about that line.

Problem: Other problem

Hardware Information: ⓘ
    MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013)
    [Technical Specifications] - [User Guide] - [Warranty & Service]
    MacBook Air - model: MacBookAir6,2
    1 1.3 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU: 2-core
    4 GB RAM Not upgradeable
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            2 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            2 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
    Bluetooth: Good - Handoff/Airdrop2 supported
    Wireless:  en0: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
    Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 623

Video Information: ⓘ
    Intel HD Graphics 5000
        Color LCD 1280 x 800

System Software: ⓘ
    macOS Sierra  10.12 (16A320) - Time since boot: about 2 hours

Disk Information: ⓘ
    APPLE SSD SM0256F disk0 : (251 GB) (Solid State - TRIM: Yes)
        EFI (disk0s1)  : 210 MB
        Recovery HD (disk0s3)   [Recovery]: 650 MB
        Untitled (disk1) /  [Startup]: 249.78 GB (66.35 GB free)
            Encrypted AES-XTS Unlocked
            Core Storage: disk0s2 250.14 GB Online

USB Information: ⓘ
    Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub
        Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller

Thunderbolt Information: ⓘ
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Gatekeeper: ⓘ
    Anywhere

Kernel Extensions: ⓘ
        /Library/Application Support/Roxio
    [not loaded]    com.roxio.TDIXController (1.7 - 2014-10-17) [Support]

```
    /Library/Extensions
[loaded]    com.bongiovi.DPSReflector (1.0.6 - SDK 10.11 - 2016-10-14) [Support]

    /System/Library/Extensions
[not loaded]    com.LaCie.ScsiType00 (1.2.13 - SDK 10.5 - 2016-10-14) [Support]
[not loaded]    com.jmicron.driver.jmPeripheralDevice (2.0.4 - 2016-10-14) [Support]
[not loaded]    com.lacie.driver.LaCie_RemoteComms (1.0.1 - SDK 10.5 - 2016-10-14) [Support]
[not loaded]    com.olympus.CamBlockCommandsDevice (2.0.0 - 2016-10-14) [Support]
[not loaded]    com.olympus.CamBlockCommandsDeviceUP (2.0.0 - 2016-10-14) [Support]
[not loaded]    com.oxsemi.driver.OxsemiDeviceType00 (1.28.13 - SDK 10.5 - 2016-10-14) [Support]
[not loaded]    org.dungeon.driver.SATSMARTDriver (0.9 - SDK 10.7 - 2016-10-14) [Support]

    /System/Library/Extensions/OlympusDSCDriver.kext/Contents/PlugIns
[not loaded]    com.olympus.CamFWSerialBusProtocolTransport (2.0.0 - 2006-11-30) [Support]
[not loaded]    com.olympus.CamUSBMassStorageClass (2.0.0 - 2006-11-30) [Support]
```

System Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    8 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    167 Apple tasks
    [running]    80 Apple tasks
    [killed]    16 Apple tasks
    16 processes killed due to insufficient RAM

System Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    37 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    160 Apple tasks
    [running]    93 Apple tasks
    [killed]    13 Apple tasks
    13 processes killed due to insufficient RAM

Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    com.amazon.sendtokindle.launcher.plist (2016-09-27) [Support]
    [not loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist (2016-08-05) [Support]
    [failed]    com.maintain.PurgeInactiveMemory.plist (2014-11-02)
    [not loaded]    com.maintain.Restart.plist (2014-10-23)
    [not loaded]    com.maintain.ShutDown.plist (2014-10-23)
    [not loaded]    com.maintain.SystemEvents.plist (2014-10-23)
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist (2015-07-03) [Support]
    [running]    jp.co.canon.ScanGearMF.appl.Canon-MF-Scan-Agent.plist (2012-09-12) [Support]
    [running]    jp.co.canon.ScanGearMF.appl.Canon-MFSU-Agent.plist (2014-12-10) [Support]
    [not loaded]    net.culater.SIMBL.Agent.plist (2011-11-30) [Support]
    [not loaded]    org.chromium.chromoting.plist (2016-06-20) [Support]

Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist (2016-09-23) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.bombich.ccc.plist (2012-06-16) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.bresink.system.securityagent3a.plist (2014-04-17) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.daemon.plist (2016-09-01) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.klieme.TimeMachineScheduler.plist (2012-05-31) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist (2015-03-03) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (2015-07-03) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.timesoftware.timemachineeditor.backup-auto.plist (2013-01-21) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.timesoftware.timemachineeditor.helper.plist (2012-12-21) [Support]
    [failed]    com.vmware.launchd.vmware.plist (2011-05-21) [Support]
    [loaded]    net.sourceforge.MonolingualHelper.plist (2013-07-05) [Support]
    [loaded]    org.macosforge.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist (2012-05-24) [Support]

User Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    com.shoebox.launched.plist (2015-12-07) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.shoebox.launched.pliste (2015-12-07) [Support]
    [not loaded]    com.spotify.webhelper.plist (2016-10-14) [Support]
    [running]    com.srib.pssddaemon.plist (2015-07-17) [Support]

User Login Items: ⓘ
    Flux    Application  (/Applications/Flux.app)

Internet Plug-ins: ⓘ
    Flip4Mac WMV Plugin: 2.3.8.1 (2014-04-17) [Support]
    FlashPlayer-10.6: 23.0.0.185 - SDK 10.9 (2016-10-11) [Support]
    QuickTime Plugin: 7.7.3 (2016-09-06)
    Flash Player: 23.0.0.185 - SDK 10.9 (2016-10-11) [Support]
    JavaAppletPlugin: Java 8 Update 101 build 13 (2016-08-19) Check version
    SharePointBrowserPlugin: 14.3.5 - SDK 10.6 (2014-04-17) [Support]
    nplastpass: 2.0.15 (2014-04-17) [Support]
    PepperFlashPlayer: 23.0.0.185 - SDK 10.9 (2016-10-11) [Support]
    Silverlight: 5.1.50709.0 - SDK 10.6 (2016-09-20) [Support]
    iPhotoPhotocast: 7.0 - SDK 10.8 (2014-04-17)

User internet Plug-ins: ⓘ
    CitrixOnlineWebDeploymentPlugin: 1.0.105 (2013-04-25) [Support]

Safari Extensions: ⓘ
    Adblock Plus - Eyeo GmbH - https://adblockplus.org/ (2016-10-17)
    NoMoreiTunes - Florian Pichler - http://nomoreitunes.einserver.de/ (2016-08-26)
    Tab Across - support@tabacross.com - http://tabacross.com (2016-07-15)
    Evernote Web Clipper - Evernote Corp. - http://evernote.com (2016-10-17)
    Reddit Enhancement Suite - Steve Sobel - http://redditenhancementsuite.com/ (2016-10-14)
    Save to Pocket - Read It Later, Inc. - http://getpocket.com/ (2016-06-29)
    AdBlock - BetaFish, Inc. - https://getadblock.com (2016-09-29)
    Sessions - David Yoo - https://sessions-extension.github.io/Sessions/ (2016-08-26)

3rd Party Preference Panes: ⓘ
    remoting_host_prefpane (2016-08-05) [Support]
    Flash Player (2016-09-23) [Support]
    Java (2016-08-19) [Support]
    TimeMachineScheduler (2014-04-17) [Support]

Time Machine: ⓘ
    Skip System Files: NO
    Mobile backups: ON
    Auto backup: YES
    Volumes being backed up:
        Untitled: Disk size: 249.78 GB Disk used: 183.42 GB
    Destinations:
        Seagate  [Local]
        Total size: 4.00 TB
        Total number of backups: 4
        Oldest backup: 9/7/16, 8:57 PM
        Last backup: 10/2/16, 7:29 PM
        Size of backup disk: Excellent
            Backup size 4.00 TB > (Disk size 249.78 GB X 3)

```
    Data [Network]
    Total size: 2.00 TB
    Total number of backups: 112
    Oldest backup: 4/16/14, 11:47 PM
    Last backup: 10/21/16, 3:31 AM
    Size of backup disk: Excellent
        Backup size 2.00 TB > (Disk size 249.78 GB X 3)
```

Top Processes by CPU: ⓘ
        16%    mdworker(17)
         5%    WindowServer
         2%    fontd
         2%    kernel_task
         1%    launchd

Top Processes by Memory: ⓘ
    827 MB    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent(6)
    524 MB    kernel_task
    324 MB    mdworker(17)
    279 MB    Safari
    98 MB    iTunes

Virtual Memory Information: ⓘ
    18 MB    Free RAM
    3.98 GB    Used RAM (523 MB Cached)
    240 MB    Swap Used

Diagnostics Information: ⓘ
    Oct 21, 2016, 12:10:19 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL Agent_2016-10-21-121019_[redacted].crash
        /Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax/Contents/Resources/SIMBL Agent.app/Contents/MacOS/SIMBL Agent
    Oct 21, 2016, 12:09:29 PM    Self test - passed
    Oct 21, 2016, 11:16:09 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL Agent_2016-10-21-111609_[redacted].crash
    Oct 21, 2016, 11:00:51 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/mds_stores_2016-10-21-110051_[redacted].cpu_res ource.diag [Details]
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework /Versions/A/Support/mds_stores
    Oct 21, 2016, 09:12:27 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/StellarDriveToolBox_2016-10-21-091227_[redacte d].crash
        /Applications/StellarDriveToolBox.app/Contents/MacOS/StellarDriveToolBox.app/Co ntents/MacOS/StellarDriveToolBox
    Oct 21, 2016, 09:11:40 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/StellarDriveToolBox_2016-10-21-091140_[redacte d].crash
    Oct 21, 2016, 09:11:00 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL Agent_2016-10-21-091100_[redacted].crash
    Oct 21, 2016, 07:15:09 AM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/StellarDriveToolBox_2016-10-21-071509_[redacte d].crash
    Oct 21, 2016, 03:08:13 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/TMScheduler_2016-10-21-030813_[redacted].crash
        /Library/PreferencePanes/TimeMachineScheduler.prefPane/Contents/Resources/TMSch eduler
    Oct 20, 2016, 08:11:03 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/StellarDriveToolBox_2016-10-20-201103_[redacte d].crash
    Oct 20, 2016, 08:09:57 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/StellarDriveToolBox_2016-10-20-200957_[redacte d].crash
    Oct 20, 2016, 07:49:42 PM    ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL Agent_2016-10-20-194942_[redacted].crash
    Oct 19, 2016, 06:13:56 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/TMScheduler_2016-10-19-181356_[redacted].crash
    Oct 18, 2016, 07:28:28 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2016-10-18-192828_[redacted].cpu_resourc e.diag [Details]
        /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the **Install OS X El Capitan.app** from macOS Sierra you need to create a USB Installer and boot the Mac with it.  You'll also need to erase the Macintosh HD and perform a clean install.  **Make sure you have proper User Data Backups from which to restore your Data before erasing the Macintosh HD.**

Have a look at [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/HT201372). Excerpt show below:

> **Use the 'createinstallmedia' command in Terminal**
>
> 1. Download the OS X installer from the Mac App Store. Quit the installer if it opens automatically after downloading. The installer
>      will be in your Applications folder.
> 2. Mount your USB flash drive or other volume. You could also use a secondary internal partition.
> 3. Open the Terminal app, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
> 4. Use the `createinstallmedia` command in Terminal to create the bootable installer. Examples of this command are in the next section.
>      For detailed usage instructions, make sure that the appropriate
>      Install OS X app is in your Applications folder, then enter one of the
>      following paths in Terminal:
>
> **Path for El Capitan:**
>
> ```
> /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
> ```
>
> **Examples**
>
> This is the basic syntax of the command. Replace *`volumepath`* with
>   the path to your USB flash drive or other volume, and replace
>   *`installerpath`* with the path to the Install OS X app.
>
> ```
> createinstallmedia --volume volumepath --applicationpath installerpath
> ```
>
> The following examples assume that the OS X installer is in your
>   Applications folder and the name of your USB flash drive or other
>   volume is MyVolume:
>
> **Example for El Capitan:**
>
> ```
> sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app
> ```